# Can i change this code to make it stop my raspberry pi car when no key is pressed? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

First off, I have Q set to the stop function for my car, but I would like to make it so the car only moves when a key is pressed. E.g., when I press W the car goes forward, but I have to use Q to stop the car. I want to make it so that I have to hold down W for the car to go forward, and when I release the W key I want the car to stop.

I have worked at this for a while now as a school project, but I am getting nowhere because I don't know what to search for on Google or there's no info on the topic. So I have come here to see if anyone can help me. Thanks in advance for anyone who takes any time in helping me resolve my problem.

Here is my code. I don't care if you completely change it to achieve what I want, as long as it still works in my scenario. If there's any more info you need, please feel free to ask me in the comments.

*Even though it's for a school project, I will put in my report that I had to post this here and that the person who finds a fix will get credited for the help. :)

```
import RPi.GPIO as io
io.setmode(io.BCM)
import time, sys, tty, termios
from termcolor import colored, cprint

motor1_in1_pin = 4
motor1_in2_pin = 17
io.setup(motor1_in1_pin, io.OUT)
io.setup(motor1_in2_pin, io.OUT)

motor2_in1_pin = 24
motor2_in2_pin = 25
motor2_in3_pin = 22
io.setup(motor2_in1_pin, io.OUT)
io.setup(motor2_in2_pin, io.OUT)
io.setup(motor2_in3_pin, io.OUT)


io.setup(18, io.OUT)
io.output(18, False)


io.setup(23, io.OUT)
io.output(23, False)


io.setup(27, io.OUT)
io.output(27, False)

def getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch




def motor1_forward():
    io.output(motor1_in1_pin, True)
    io.output(motor1_in2_pin, False)

def motor1_reverse():
    io.output(motor1_in1_pin, False)
    io.output(motor1_in2_pin, True)

def motor1_stop():
    io.output(motor1_in1_pin, False)
    io.output(motor1_in2_pin, False)

def motor2_forward():
    io.output(motor2_in1_pin, True)
    io.output(motor2_in2_pin, False)
    io.output(motor2_in3_pin, False)

def motor2_reverse():
    io.output(motor2_in1_pin, False)
    io.output(motor2_in2_pin, True)
    io.output(motor2_in3_pin, True)

def motor2_stop():
    io.output(motor2_in1_pin, False)
    io.output(motor2_in2_pin, False)
    io.output(motor2_in3_pin, False)

def toggleLights():

    global lightStatus

    if(lightStatus == False):
        io.output(18, True)
        io.output(23, True)
        lightStatus = True
    else:
        io.output(18, False)
        io.output(23, False)
        lightStatus = False



def toggleSteering(direction):

    global wheelStatus

    if(direction == "right"):
        if(wheelStatus == "centre"):
            motor1_forward()         
            wheelStatus = "right"
        elif(wheelStatus == "left"):
            motor1_stop()
            wheelStatus = "centre"

    if(direction == "left"):
        if(wheelStatus == "centre"):
            motor1_reverse()
            wheelStatus = "left"
        elif(wheelStatus == "right"):
            motor1_stop()
            wheelStatus = "centre"


io.output(motor1_in1_pin, False)
io.output(motor1_in2_pin, False)
io.output(motor2_in1_pin, False)
io.output(motor2_in2_pin, False)
io.output(motor2_in3_pin, False)

lightStatus2 = False
lightStatus = False
wheelStatus = "centre"


bold = "\033[1m"
reset = "\033[0;0m"
cprint("Jacksons Awesome Rc car Program", 'blue')
print " " +bold + "w/s:" +reset + " Acceleration"
print " " +bold + "a/d:" +reset + " Steering"
print " " +bold + "q:" +reset + " Brake"
print("l: lights")
print("p: Dishwasher")



while True:
    char = getch()  
    if(char == "w"):
        motor2_forward()

    if(char == "q"):
        motor2_stop()

    if(char == "s"):
        motor2_reverse()

    if(char == "q"):
        motor2_stop()

    if(char == "a"):
        toggleSteering("left")

    if(char == "d"):
        toggleSteering("right")

    if(char == "l"):
        toggleLights()

    if(char == "o"):
        cPrint("hi", 'red')

    if(char == "p"):
        print " " +bold + "Dishwasher is a mechanical device for cleaning dishes and eating-utensils. Dishwashers can be found in restaurants and private homes" +reset + " "

    if(char == "x"):
        cprint("Program Ended", 'red')
        break

    char = ""




io.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use 'elif' instead of 'if' statements.  With your way, if the key is 'w' then your program still goes through and tests for 'a', 'd', 'l'... etc.  With 'elif', once it reaches a true condition, it stops checking the rest of the conditions (for efficiency).

Here's what I came up with...

It checks the key pressed and if it ISN'T a forward/backward command, it does what it should do.  If it IS a forward/backward command, it moves that direction for the given amount of time, then stops and checks to see the next key pressed.

Keep in mind I only edited your 'while' loop.

```
import time

while True:
    char = getch()  

    if(char == "w"):
        motor2_forward()
    elif(char == "s"):
        motor2_reverse()
    elif(char == "a"):
        toggleSteering("left")
        continue
    elif(char == "d"):
        toggleSteering("right")
        continue
    elif(char == "l"):
        toggleLights()
        continue
    elif(char == "o"):
        cPrint("hi", 'red')
        continue
    elif(char == "p"):
        print " " +bold + "Dishwasher is a mechanical device for cleaning dishes and eating-utensils. Dishwashers can be found in restaurants and private homes" +reset + " "
        continue
    elif(char == "x"):
        cprint("Program Ended", 'red')
        break
    else
        continue

    time.sleep(1)
    motor2_stop()
```

Other problems noticed:
You seem to have 2 motors, but only run 'motor2'.  I don't see any direction to 'motor1'.  Also, if the 1 second time limit is too long for a proper response, you can use a floating point number for a shorter duration.

And finally, if this helped you, I'd prefer to have an up vote (or my answer selected) rather than recognition on a project for some teacher I don't know.

Comment: I just get this error from your code   File "rc_car2.py", line 155
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Also i am using an l293d chip so motor 1 is for the steering motor

Comment: the last else needs a colon (:)